# quantiﬁer equivalences in Logic

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, logic, proof-writing

Good official evening community,

The book gives me the following sentence and tells me to create a ﬁle with Fitch, enter the sentence, and check it using FO Co. (With no premises)

¬∃zSmall(z) ↔ ∃z¬Small(z)

I do not know where to start.

Would you please help me

Thank you

Mark

Comment: So ... did you check it with FO Con?

Comment: I did but it did not check

Comment: FO Con is right! ... what is your question?

Comment: it says if the sentence is not true then create a counterexample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FO Con will say that this is not a First order logic tautology, because $\neg \exists z \ Small(z)$ is not equivalent to $\exists z \neg Small(z)$

$\neg \exists z \ Small(z)$ is saying that there are no small objects at all.

$\exists z \neg Small(z)$ is saying that there is some object that is not small ... but that does not rule out that there may be other objects that are small.

So, do you see how to create a counterexample?

Comment: @markjohn Yay! Good for you :)